# Connect a Spring app to MongoDB using Docker Compose

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have started learning Docker and I attempted to connect my Spring app to MongoDB. I followed all the instructions precisely, but I am unable to identify the issue.

Here is the code I used:

application.properties

```
server.port=5000
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=demoDb
debug=true
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim

WORKDIR /app



COPY target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

i got this error:

```
demo-web-1      | 2023-08-21 13:45:05.265  INFO 1 --- [}-mongodb:27070] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb:27070
demo-web-1      | 
demo-web-1      | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
demo-web-1      |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
demo-web-1      |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
demo-web-1      |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
demo-web-1      |       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
demo-web-1      |       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
demo-web-1      | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Comment: Exposed port is `27017` and you are connecting to `27070`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I checked and I didn't know why it was on port 27070. I used "docker-compose build" to recreate the image, and it worked.